# How to enable tracing profiling in jvisualvm?

Tags: java, debugging, profiling, trace, jvisualvm

I've [read](https://engineering.talkdesk.com/ninjas-guide-to-getting-started-with-visualvm-f8bff061f7e7) that jvisualVm can do tracing profile.

So I ran jvisualVm on my local pc and I see following:
[image]

According the materials I read that jvisualVm allows to use tracing profiling on `Profiler` tab and it must look like:

[image]

But as you can see I don't have it. I tried to find button to show that tab but I was not successful.

How can I enable it?

P.S.

According the @Alexandar Petrov answer I tried to add plugun manually so I visited https://visualvm.github.io/uc/release14/updates.html and downloaded `Tracer-JVM Probes` The next step was to add file I downloaded:

[image]

but when I select file and click open - nothing happens - neither error nor anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://visualvm.github.io/plugins.html you will find the Tracer plugin there.

Here is a download link with all plugins for Java 8. What you need to download is under Tracer probes. The one that you 100% need is Tracer-JVM Probes the rest is optional.

https://visualvm.github.io/uc/8u131/updates.html

After you donwload you need to go to `Tools->Plugins->Downloaded->Add Plugin` and select the nbm file with the tracer plugin. When you do that you will get a screen where it gives you the list of the dependencies. You need to download all the dependencies and select them together with the plugin for installation as it is showed on this screenshot:
[image]

After you have installed it the java visual VM will get restarted and you will be able to see the tracer in a separate tab. Here is my screen notice tha tracer tab besides the Sampler tab:

[image]

Comment: I do select nbm file but nothing  happens: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2019/05/30/0005/3037/338909/09/30159285bc.jpg

Comment: @gstackoverflow did you install the dependencies as well ? You need to download the dependencies.

Comment: I use jvisualvm from java 8 jdk

Comment: @gstackoverflow I use the same. Why don't you just download the dependencies from my screenshot and install all together ?

Comment: I did everything you wrote but it doesn't work as I wrote above. Which URL do you use for downloads?

Comment: The one i posted, i downloaded manuelt all the dependencies in the screenshot added them and installed them all at once.

Comment: Re-install java and begin from the start.What i have posted is working did it myself today.